# elegant way to read large data with FilterInputStream object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, large-files, java-io

I am getting a `FilterInputStream` object as a return type from a function. Now the file which I will be getting as an stream is a log file. So I think it can be big file. So I do not want to read the data all at once. But reading data in a loop is kind of tedious job.

I need splitting at every newline, meaning data in file is in line separated format. With a constant size byte array to be used in `public int read(byte[], int off, int len)` as it will give rise to many cases. I do not want to read it at once because it can be of large size.

Is there an elegant way to do this.

P.S.: I am in particularly referring to [S3ObjectInputStream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html) extended from `FilterInputStream` which has `read()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap a `BufferedReader` around an `InputStreamReader` around the `FilterInputStream` and call `readLine().`

Comment: And make sure to specify an encoding in the InputStreamReader.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I am sorry, the next floor is right, you can use BufferedReader class, it has a method called readLine,and it returns a String object instead of a byte array. Just like this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("the file path")));
String date = reader.readLine();
if(!StringUtil.isBlank(date)){
    //reade the file line by line
    date = reader.readLine();
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: I don't know what 'next floor' means. `StringUtil.isBlank()` isn't necessarily a valid reason to stop reading the file, but you do need to check *every* `readLine()` result for null before doing anything else with it. The variable name should be `data,` or `line,` not `date.` This code doesn't read the entire file. -1